# DatagridView was null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Такая, казалось бы тривиальная проблема, но не могу понять, в чем дело. В Windows Forms создаю объект DataGridView
Соединяюсь с базой данных PostgreSql через app config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="localDBConnection" connectionString="Host=localhost;port=5432;database=postgres;uid = postgres; password = 1234;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

И соответствующим вызовом в теле метода:

```
string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Подключение работает, я таким образом создавал таблицу, получал данные из таблицы.
Если я создаю dataGridView в коде, то он выводит данные:

```
            DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
            this.Controls.Add(grid);
            using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(
                       connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
                ds.Reset();
                da.Fill(ds);            
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                grid.DataSource = dt;
                connection.Close();
```

Если то же самое я сделаю, обратившись к созданному через Toolbox, то мне выйдет ошибка, что dataGridView1 was null. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Метод `InitializeComponent` в конструкторе формы вызывается?

Comment: Да, вызывается. public Form1()
        {
            SelectDB(sql2, myConnectionString);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Наконец-то дошло, надо было поместить метод после InitializeComponent. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Здесь всё хуже, чем просто переместить метод. Никогда не вставляйте свой код в конструктор формы, используйте обработчик события `Form.Load` вместо этого. И это не потому что "так красиво", а потому что у конструктора есть свои особенности, то есть ограничения, которые рано или поздно начнут вас удивлять. Лучше сразу сделать нормально в обработчике.